# Overwrite font-weight in @font-face

Tags: css, font-face

Currently I'm using `@font-face`with a fallback for not supported browsers:

```
@font-face
{
  font-family: TheSansBlack;
  src: local( TheSansBlack ), url( ../fonts/TheSans_TT9_.woff ) format( 'woff' );
}

font-family: TheSansBlack, Arial, Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
```

In some cases the fallback should be bold, so I have some css notations like:

```
#foo
{
  font-family: TheSansBlack, Arial, Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

And because I'm using a font called `TheSansBlack`there's no need to set `font-weight: bold`

But this won't work:

```
@font-face
{
  font-family: TheSansBlack;
  font-weight: normal;
  src: local( TheSansBlack ), url( ../fonts/TheSans_TT9_.woff ) format( 'woff' );
}
```

It still displays the bold one which looks ugly, because it's double bold with TheSansBlack...
I just need to set font-weight to bold on the fallback, not the woff font.

EDIT: I also tried this without success:

```
@font-face
{
  font-family: TheSansBlack;
  src: local( TheSansBlack ), url( ../fonts/TheSans_TT9_.woff ) format( 'woff' );

  #foo
  {
    font-weight: normal !important;
  }
}

#foo
{
  font-family: TheSansBlack, Arial, Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: hi can u put the html code and jsfiddle link ?

Comment: @azad how to do that with a non-free font? ;-) isn't it useless then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it :-)

I had to set font-weight explicitly to bold in @font-face.

Dunno why...

EDIT: full example

```
@font-face
{
  src: local( TheSansBlack ), url( ../fonts/TheSans_TT9_.woff ) format( 'woff' );
  font-family: TheSansBlack;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#foo
{
  font-family: TheSansBlack, Arial, Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

This results in normal TheSansBlack and bold Arial/Verdana/Helvetica in older browsers.

Comment: The reason is that the font-weight inside font-face tells your browser that the font *is* the bold variant.